Integrate PowerBI with React App : crypto_nonexistent error
I am trying to embed PowerBI report in a react app. I have followed this example from microsoft. The example is in Typescript but I am using Javascript
Here is my index.js file.
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthProvider";
import { CountryProvider } from "./context/CountryProvider";
import theme from "./theme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store/store";
import * as config from "./pages/powerbi/keys";
import { LogLevel, PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";

// TRIED THIS TO FIX THE ISSUE
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && !window.crypto) {
  window.crypto = window.msCrypto;
}

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
  auth: {
      clientId: config.clientId,
      authority: config.authorityUrl,
      redirectUri: "http://{SERVER_IP_ADDRESS}/FOLDER_NAME/"
  },
  cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage', 
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        console.log(`LEVEL: ${level} MESSAGE: ${message}`);
      },
      piiLoggingEnabled: false,
      logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose
    },
    cryptoOptions: {
      usePkce: false // TRIED THIS TO FIX THE ISSUE
    }
  }
});

console.log("CRYPTO: ", window.crypto);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
   <div id="MainDiv">
      <Provider store={store}>
         <BrowserRouter basename="Reactjs_Demo/">
            <AuthProvider>
               <CountryProvider>
                  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                     <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
                     <App />
                     </MsalProvider>
                  </ThemeProvider>
               </CountryProvider>
            </AuthProvider>
         </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
   </div>
);


And this is the PowerBI component
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, useContext } from "react";
import { AuthenticationResult, InteractionType, EventType, AuthError } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { MsalContext } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { service, factories, models } from "powerbi-client";
import * as config from "./keys";

const powerbi = new service.Service(factories.hpmFactory, factories.wpmpFactory, factories.routerFactory);

export default function PowerBiReport() {
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("");
    const [embedUrl, setEmbedUrl] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState([]);
    const reportRef = useRef(null);
    const context = useContext(MsalContext);

    const authenticate = () => {
        const msalInstance = context.instance;
        const msalAccounts = context.accounts;
        const msalInProgress = context.inProgress;
        const isAuthenticated = context.accounts.length > 0;

        if (error.length > 0) {
            return;
        }

        const eventCallback = msalInstance.addEventCallback((message) => {
            if (message.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS && !accessToken) {
                const payload = message.payload;
                const name = payload.account?.name ? payload.account?.name : "";
                setAccessToken(payload.accessToken);
                setUsername(name);
                tryRefreshUserPermissions();
            }
        });

        const loginRequest = { scopes: config.scopeBase, account: msalAccounts[0] };

        if (!isAuthenticated && msalInProgress === InteractionType.None) {
            msalInstance.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
        } else if (isAuthenticated && accessToken && !embedUrl) {
            getEmbedUrl();
            msalInstance.removeEventCallback(eventCallback);
        } else if (isAuthenticated && !accessToken && !embedUrl && msalInProgress === InteractionType.None) {
            setUsername(msalAccounts[0].name);
            msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(loginRequest).then((response) => {
                setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
                getEmbedUrl();
            }).catch((error) => {
                if (error.errorCode === "consent_required" || error.errorCode === "interaction_required" || error.errorCode === "login_required") {
                    msalInstance.acquireTokenRedirect(loginRequest);
                } else if (error.errorCode === '429') {
                    setError(["Our Service Token Server (STS) is overloaded, please try again in sometime"]);
                } else {
                    setError(["There was some problem fetching the access token" + error.toString()]);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    const tryRefreshUserPermissions = () => {
        fetch(config.powerBiApiUrl + "v1.0/myorg/RefreshUserPermissions", {
            headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken },
            method: "POST"
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log("User permissions refreshed successfully.");
            } else {
                if (response.status === 429) {
                    console.error("Permissions refresh will be available in up to an hour.");
                } else {
                    console.error(response);
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Failure in making API call." + error);
        });
    };

    const getEmbedUrl = () => {
        fetch(config.powerBiApiUrl + "v1.0/myorg/groups/" + config.wspaceId + "/reports/" + config.reportId, {
            headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken },
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(response => {
            const errorMessage = ["Error occurred while fetching the embed URL of the report", "Request Id: " + response.headers.get("requestId")];
            response.json()
            .then(body => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    setEmbedUrl(body["embedUrl"]);
                } else {
                    errorMessage.push("Error " + response.status + ": " + body.error.code);
                    setError(errorMessage);
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {
                errorMessage.push("Error " + response.status + ": An error has occurred");
                setError(errorMessage);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setError([error]);
        });
    };

    const setUsername = (username) => {
        const welcome = document.getElementById("welcome");
        if (welcome !== null) welcome.innerText = "Welcome, " + username;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (reportRef.current !== null) {
            const reportContainer = reportRef.current;
            if (error.length) {
                reportContainer.textContent = "";
                error.forEach(line => {
                    reportContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(line));
                    reportContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                });
            } else if (accessToken !== "" && embedUrl !== "") {
                const embedConfiguration = {
                    type: "report",
                    tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
                    accessToken,
                    embedUrl,
                    id: config.reportId,
                };
                const report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, embedConfiguration);
                report.off("loaded");
                report.on("loaded", () => {
                    console.log("Report load successful");
                });
                report.off("rendered");
                report.on("rendered", () => {
                    console.log("Report render successful");
                });
                report.off("error");
                report.on("error", (event) => {
                    const errorMsg = event.detail;
                    console.error(errorMsg);
                });
            }
        }
    }, [accessToken, embedUrl, error]);

    useEffect(() => {
        authenticate();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            if (reportRef.current) {
                powerbi.reset(reportRef.current);
            }
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="welcome"></div>
            <div ref={reportRef}>
                Loading the report...
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};



I don't get any error when I am running the project locally on port 3000. But when I deploy to the server I get following error
Uncaught BrowserAuthError: crypto_nonexistent: The crypto object or function is not available.

this project was created using CRA. How to solve this?

check the browser Compatibility that which supports the Web Crypto API.

@SureshChikkam can you kindly explain how to do that? because when I am developing in my local env I am using chrome. and when I deploy to the server I am still using chrome.

crypto API is only available in secure contexts. If the server is running on HTTP, switch to HTTPS.

If enabling HTTPS is not feasible immediately, you can use a polyfill for the crypto API. this is I won't recommend for production due to potential security risks (Temporary Solution).

@Mahmud_Mridul, how your application is being hosted on the server. Nginx, Apache, or IIS?,
or cloud service like Azure App Service or AWS?,
or custom Node.js server?

IIS, windows server

Use a certificate from a trusted Certificate Authority (CA) or create a self-signed certificate for internal testing. You can use IIS Manager to create or import the certificate.

Does your server running on HTTPS?

no it uses HTTP

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

To enable HTTPS for the React application hosted on IIS on a Windows Server. You’ll need an SSL certificate to enable HTTPS.
Create a self-signed certificate for internal testing. use IIS Manager to create or import the certificate.
Open IIS Manager


Double-click Server Certificates.

In the Actions panel, click Create Self-Signed Certificate.



Name it (e.g., MyTestCert), and it will appear in the list.

After creating SSL certificate bind the Certificate to the Site.

Navigate to the application/site under the Sites node.



In the right-hand panel, click Bindings.

Add an https binding and select your SSL certificate.



Select HTTPS.


MSAL authentication recommend using HTTPS, especially for production apps. MSAL trying to use the crypto API for authentication tasks (like generating tokens). You can configure MSAL with custom crypto options to prevent errors when crypto is unavailable.
